# globally change my textsize in android

Tags: textview, android

I created an activity with 15 textview in android. This textview is custom textview which extends textview. I define properties in its xml with different textsizes. I want to change textsize globally to affect all 15 textview. Is it possible? if yes how? can anyone help me.